# How to protect a file under a writable directory

Tags: linux, file, unix, permissions, acl

I am coming across some problem with file permission and acl.
I've got a writable directory name "dir" with the permission 777 (dir rwxrwxrwx)
Under dir I create a file tmp.txt (dir/tmp.txt)

I was wondering how can I stop other/group members to edit/delete the file while not changing the permission of "dir". Everyone is free take any action as they like to the other file/directory under "dir".

I was wondering maybe "setfacl" or what.

Comment: can't you just use chmod on the file itself?

Comment: cuz i want to allow other operations such as create or edit other files or directory under "dur"

Comment: @lyinch After `chmod 600 dir/tmp.txt` a group member can `rm dir/tmp.txt; echo "New content" > dir/tmp.txt`.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever owns the directory can delete the files within it, even if they are owned by root.

There are two ways to get you to almost where you want.

### Idea 1 - Sticky Bit

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 33 root root 1020 2020-03-14 14:06 /tmp/
```

This is the common permissions for Unix `/tmp` directory. That `t` there at the end of the permissions denotes the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit), you can set it by running:

```
chmod +t /tmp
```

The sticky bit says that even though everyone has write permission on the directory, the only ones who can delete a file under that directory are root, the directory owner, and the file's owner.

### Idea 2 - Extra Directory

A directory cannot be deleted if it's not empty. If you put your files in a directory that's owned by you, where only you (and root) can delete files, then nobody else can delete it:

```
root@playground# tree -up
.
`-- [drwxrwxrwx root    ]  box
    |-- [-rw-r--r-- test1   ]  f1
    `-- [drwxr-xr-x test2   ]  hello
        `-- [-rw-r--r-- test2   ]  f2

2 directories, 2 files
root@playground# su test1
test1@playground$ rm box/hello
rm: cannot remove ‘box/hello’: Is a directory
test1@playground$ rm -rf box/hello/
rm: cannot remove ‘box/hello/f2’: Permission denied
```